# How do i make a multi-threaded server in perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, multithreading

I have looked online at making a multi-threaded server in perl, but i cannot find any good ones that clearly explain how to create one. I have created a server and client in perl but i do not seem to be able to make it multi-threaded. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you compile perl with 'pthreads' support?

Comment: Do you really need multiple threads?  If you want to handle multiple connections asynchronously, you can use `select` to handle multiplexed IO tasks.  You could also fork child processes as needed to handle individual connections.

Comment: a 'libevent' asynchronous event loop or a forking server are almost always better choices than a multi-threaded one

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the [Net::Server](http://search.cpan.org/~rhandom/Net-Server-0.97/lib/Net/Server.pod) CPAN module (rather than rolling your own), you could make use of [Net::Server::Coro](http://search.cpan.org/~alexmv/Net-Server-Coro-0.8/lib/Net/Server/Coro.pm) to build a multi-threded server. Note that Net::Server can handle (pre)forking (i.e. multi-processes) servers and these may be easer to use.

Comment: I have no idea how to use Net::Server. And I do not need a multi-thread server persay, but i am wanting to learn how to program. I am wanting a multi-thread server so multiple clients can connect and i can send them all commands

Comment: You can use select to wait on events (including 'can_write') on multiple sockets, or one of the asynchronous event loop modules (AnyEvent, Coro, EV, Event, IO::Async, POE) to create a single process server that can handle multiple clients. Otherwise look into using fork to handle separate clients.

Comment: would i use fork to send commands to all clients at the same time?

Comment: A starting point for Net::Server would be to modify the code at http://search.cpan.org/~rhandom/Net-Server-0.97/lib/Net/Server.pod#SAMPLE_CODE (which echos input back to multiple clients) to do whatever it is you have already written. To give you more specific advice, I think we need to know what you want your sever to do. We could list asynchronous Perl libraries all day.

Answer (score 3):

I think POE might be what you're looking for.
See the [POE Cookbook](http://poe.perl.org/?POE_Cookbook) for examples.

Comment: I'd second this suggestion.  If you want a server to be able to handle simultaneous communications with multiple clients then POE would be a good fit.  It takes some effort to get your head around but it's worth it.